# What is the identity of this flower found in Mavericks Beach in Half Moon Bay, California, USA?

Tags: species-identification, botany, flowers

Please help identify this flower I saw in Mavericks Beach in Half Moon Bay, California. It was smelling soooo good, you can feel from distance. I want to buy and plant in my garden.

Thank you,

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the habitat, color, and size that lupine looks like [Coastal bush lupine](https://www.calflora.org/cgi-bin/species_query.cgi?where-calrecnum=5106) (*Lupinus arboreus*).

Please note that Coastal bush lupine can be invasive, so be responsible about where you plant it!

You can also learn more about this plant and its growth requirements from [the California Native Plant Society](https://calscape.org/Lupinus-arboreus-())

Images for comparison:
[image: © 2009 Heather Ellison]
[image: © 2019 Mary Conway, CC BY-NC 4.0]